# Place Advanced Installer feature files in app data?

Tags: advanced-installer

My application uses extensions that must be placed in the the folder `[AppDataFolder]\A\B\C`... But Advanced Installer features do not allow me to put my files in a "*system folder*".
I really need a workaround for this limitation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 1 more hour of research, I have spotted an interesting piece of knowledge on the user manual.
**`"Uppercase identifier"`**
The trick was to have a folder with an uppercase identifier in the `Files and Folders` section. For this you either have to change the name of the folder to uppercase, like `"LOL"` or change it's identifier... somehow.

Comment: They are called public properties: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/properties.html . Private properties (which contain lowercase letters in their names) do not keep their modified values during install.